# Crash due to memory issue with pushing UIViewController in iOS multiple times. No crash trace

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, crash, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following scenario. (All programmatically implemented - No Storyboard)

Xcode 9.4, Swift 4.1

- A mainViewController with a tableView
- When a cell is selected, I push a VC into the stack with:

```
let detailVC = DetailViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```

- The detail VC has a subview (GalleyView: `UIView`)

I can push the detailVC and go back using the `navigationBar` back button multiple times with out a problem.

But... When I add 3 UIImageViews as subviews to the Gallery View, I can push the detailVC, but every time the time to load is longer and after 4 times (and about 2 secs), it crashes (Totally deterministic)

The only message is the following, and no Crash Stack Trace in Xcode.

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

Monitoring the memory usage, it is in the 15MB to 25MB range without any evident increase between push/pop operations.

I was able to pinpoint the issue to the addSubview(imageView) in the galleryView

- If I comment the `addSubview` line, it works, but with the imageViews added to the gallery View, it crashes after 5 push operations.
- The crash does not happen in the specific addSubview line, but after `viewWillAppear()` ended, but right before `viewDidAppear()` in the detailVC.
- Fails in the device and in the simulator

I have made sure that I am not pushing a VC recursively or adding the views or the imageViews multiple times. I instantiate the objects every time. The gallery.subViews.count is always at 3.

Any ideas of what may be happening here?... e

Comment: Did you run instruments and see where the memory get accumulated ?

Comment: Adding further @Gihan's comment, use Leaks/Allocations in Instruments with the record reference counts and nszombie options switched on to track it further down.

Comment: Thx @Gian for the recommendation.  I was relying too much in the Memory usage shown in the Xcode's Debug Navigator pane that showed a flat memory usage.  In instruments, the Anonymous VM Memory was jumping big time with every push (50MB each time). The previous detailVC is not released from memory after the pop. I fixed it moving the detailVC to be a property in the table class with an .update(withDetail:) method, instead of instantiating a new detailVC each time it is pushed.